# How to enumerate and print characters in Ctype character classes?

Tags: php, locale

The PHP Ctype extension provides functions for checking whether a character belongs to a particular character class (e.g. ctype_punct() for punctuation).  How can you enumerate and print all the characters that belong to each class (per the current locale settings)?

My best idea was to iterate from 0 to 255, calling each ctype_*() function to see whether that character value belongs to each class.  But doing so gives only the numeric values corresponding to the characters in each class, and I could not find a way to actually print the characters corresponding to those numeric values.  chr() works only for ASCII values 0-127, not 128-255.

For instance, in a locale using ISO 8859-1, 163 would be considered punctuation, and should be printed as "£".